# craft.fields.getFieldByHandle() has been deprecated

Tags: deprecation

I'm querying a dropdown field to loop through all of the options and followed best practice (so I thought) in the twig template. Does anyone know how to update for the deprecation below?

Deprecation message:

> craft.fields.getFieldByHandle() has been deprecated. Use craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle() instead.

Code line:
`{% set siteOptions = craft.fields.getFieldbyHandle('siteSelector').settings.options %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `craft.fields.getFieldbyHandle()` with `craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle()` (note the additional `.app` in there).