# Craft 4: How do I get field by handle?

Tags: templating, craft4

In Craft 2, I used to be able to do this:
https://craftcms.com/docs/2.x/templating/craft.fields.html#getfieldbyhandle-handle

```
{% set body = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('body') %}
{{ body.instructions }}
```

In Craft 4 this no longer works - is there an updated syntax?
I need to be able to get the field name when I only have its handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the Fields service (this changed in Craft 3):

```
{% set body = craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle('body') %}
```

For more info see [Common Services](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/global-variables.html#common-services) in the docs.

Comment: Thank you! I realised this at the exact same time you posted your answer of course! I'll accept your answer with thanks however.

Answer (score 1):

I see craft.fields.getFieldByHandle() is deprecated and replaced with craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle()

See: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/35811/4060